# How to align elements so similar elements display in same row

Tags: html, css

This is my current display.[image]

Add to cart button is not displaying in row because 3rd element product name is bit lengthy.

This is the code for displaying the products.

```
<div>
    <div class='box' ng-repeat="product in ProductService.Products | filter:{'SubCategoryID': SCId.toString()}:true | orderBy:'ProductName'">

        <br>        <b>{{product.BrandName}}</b>
        <br>        {{product.ProductName}}
        <br><br>    <img src="http://localhost/{{ product.ProductImagePath }}" alt="" border=3 height=75 width=75></img>
        <br><br>    <select class="form-control btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-init="SelectedVariant = product.Variants[0]" ng-model="SelectedVariant" ng-options="variant.VariantName for variant in product.Variants" ng-change="ChangeVariant(product.ProductID, SelectedVariant.VariantID)"></select>

        <br>        <strike> {{SelectedVariant.MRP}} </strike> &nbsp; {{SelectedVariant.SellPrice}} {{SelectedVariant.InCart}}
        <br><br>        

        <div ng-if="SelectedVariant.InCart==0">
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-md" ng-click="AddToCart(product.ProductID, SelectedVariant.VariantID)">Add to Cart &nbsp;
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
            </a>
        </div>



        <div ng-if="SelectedVariant.InCart>0">

            <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="PlusItem(product.ProductID, SelectedVariant.VariantID)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
            </a>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info disabled">{{SelectedVariant.InCart}} in cart</button>


            <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="MinusItem(product.ProductID, SelectedVariant.VariantID)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> 
            </a>
        </div>  

    </div>          
</div>
```

and this is CSS style for box.

```
.box {
    margin : 5px;
    display : inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #F5FBEF;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Can some one help me so that all add to cart button or say all elements in box start at similar row. like 1,2,4,5,6 elements in the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend avoiding using `<br>` tags for content layout.

I would place all of those items (*title/image/dropdown/button*) in a separate div container where you can set the fixed height for each one of those containers, where you would set the height of the `.title` to be at least high enough to allow two lines of text.

```
<div class="boxes">
   <div class="box">
      <div class="title">Wheel <strong>Strong detergent bar</strong></div>
      <div class="image"><img src=""></div>
      <div class="price">$35</div>
      <div class="orderbutton"><button>Order now</button></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And then in .css file set the sizes for each of those classes.

Answer (score 1):

I would add an ellipsis if the title is too long so everything is one line.

Wrap you ProductName in a class

```
<span class='product-name'>{{product.ProductName}}</span>
```

Then style it

```
.product-name{
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/christianjuth/0qpry66L/) for a working example

Comment: Thanks for response. I appreciate your solution. But i don't want to add ellipsis.

Comment: No problem. I understand. Unfortunately I find sometimes  these issues do not have a perfect solution but hopefully you find something.

Answer (score 0):

> Can some one help me so that all add to cart button or say all elements in box start at similar row. like 1,2,4,5,6 elements in the display.

In this case will help css `flexbox`. But IE < 10 not support this feature.

Expected result: http://jsbin.com/micedo

Some docs: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/